# Qt/C++. Фиксированный размер map

Tags: c++, qt, map

Нужно хранить в `map` только `N` отсортированных значений.

- `map.size() < N`, тогда добавляем элементы.
- `map.size() > N`, тогда добавляем новые элементы, удаляя лишние.

Вариант не добавлять новые элементы в `map`, если достигнут лимит `N`, не подходит. Идея заключается в том, чтобы всегда хранить актуальные данные, которые обновляются.

Может при каждой операции добавления пробегать итератором и удалять лишние элементы? Как-то так:

```
map // список с 3 элементами
map.insert(); // 4 элемента
// удаляем все элементы, кроме первых 3х
```

Но мне такая реализация кажется будет медленной.

Может у кого-то есть другое, более элегантное решение?

Comment: а причем тут QT?

Comment: А какие элементы лишние? Не очень понятно. Любые?

Comment: @vegorov в ``qmap`` значения хранятся в сортированном порядке. Когда ограничиваем размер, должны получить в итоге ``N`` отсортированных элементов. Например, при N = 3 и {3, 5, 7, 10} мы получим {3, 5, 7}.

Comment: @vegorov в ``qmap`` значения хранятся в сортированном порядке. Когда ограничиваем размер, должны получить в итоге ``N`` отсортированных элементов. Например, при N = 3 и {3, 5, 7, 10} мы получим {3, 5, 7}.

Comment: Почему? Почему не 3,7,10; не 3,5,10;, не 5,7,10. Критерий какой? Первые N нужны, оставшиеся лишние ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понел, вы хотите оставлять первые `size` элементов. Тогда предложу вариант, например, такой:

```
template <size_t k, typename K, typename V,
     typename T = std::pair<K, V>>
std::map<K, V>&
inserter(std::map<K, V>& m, const T& p)
{
    m.insert(p);
    if (m.size() > k)
        m.erase(std::next(m.begin(), k), m.end());  
    return  m;
}
```

и пример использования:

```
int main() {    
    std::map<std::string, int> map;
    constexpr size_t size = 7;
    int k = 10;
    std::string s("B");
    while (k++ < 20) {
        s += char('A' + rand()% k);
        inserter<size>(map, { s, k });
    }
    // использовать map(имеет не более чем 7 элементов
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется вам подойдет QCache, которому можно установить максимальное число элементов, превышая которое ранние элементы перетираются.